# ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: vb.net

I want to execute following code.I am unable to insert csv file into Oracle database .The code is throwing "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" exception. Can someone help me with this My csv file first line look like below

```
27.06.2016;03.07.2016;1919959100;Pl-Auf  ;081933436-9001;F-600953.01-0021.IR.ALDL-M/01;0030;SWE40700;26.11.2015;26.11.2015;      30
```

I defined columns in SAP_ZPCP12 TABLE as

```
ID                   NUMBER
VONDATUM             DATE
BISDATUM             DATE
AUFTRAG              NUMEBER
DISPOEL              VARCHAR2
MATERIAL             VARCHAR2
BEZEICHNUNG          VARCHAR2
VRG                  VARCHAR2
ARBPLATZ             VARCHAR2
TERMSTART            DATE
TERMENDE             DATE
VORMENGE             NUMBER



Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Public Function csvToDatatable(ByVal filename As String, ByVal separator As String)

        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
        Dim firstLine As Boolean = True
        If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
            Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)
                dt.Columns.Add("VONDATUM")
                dt.Columns.Add("BISDATUM")
                dt.Columns.Add("AUFTRAG")
                dt.Columns.Add("DISPOEL")
                dt.Columns.Add("MATERIAL")
                dt.Columns.Add("BEZEICHNUNG")
                dt.Columns.Add("VRG")
                dt.Columns.Add("ARBPLATZ")
                dt.Columns.Add("TERMSTART")
                dt.Columns.Add("TERMENDE")
                dt.Columns.Add("VORMENGE")

                While Not sr.EndOfStream
                    Dim data() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(separator)
                    dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray)
                End While
            End Using
        End If
        Return dt

    End Function
    Sub Main()
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\bhogapud\Desktop\SAP_Transfer\EP1000022179500001final.csv"


        Dim finaldt As DataTable = csvToDatatable(path, ";")

        Dim oledbcn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.SQL_Server)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        For Each Row As DataRow In finaldt.Rows
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SAP_ZPCP12(ID, VONDATUM, BISDATUM, AUFTRAG, DISPOEL,MATERIAL, BEZEICHNUNG, VRG, ARBPLATZ, TERMSTART, TERMENDE, VORMENGE)
                               values (SEQ_SAP_ZPCP12.NEXTVAL, :VONDATUM, :BISDATUM, :AUFTRAG, :DISPOEL, :MATERIAL, :BEZEICHNUNG, :VRG, :ARBPLATZ, :TERMSTART, :TERMENDE, :VORMENGE )"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":VONDATUM", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(0), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":BISDATUM", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(1), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":AUFTRAG", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Row(2)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":DISPOEL", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(3)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":MATERIAL", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(4)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":BEZEICHNUNG", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(5)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":VRG", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(6)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":ARBPLATZ", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(7)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":TERMSTART", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(8), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":TERMENDE", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(9), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":VORMENGE", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Row(10)
            cmd.Connection = oledbcn
            oledbcn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            oledbcn.Close()

        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You have alot of whitespace in your csv (e.g. last parameter). `Trim()` the string after reading the line from csv and before adding the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced named variables with "?" code worked

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SAP_ZPCP12(ID, VONDATUM, BISDATUM, AUFTRAG, DISPOEL,MATERIAL, BEZEICHNUNG, VRG, ARBPLATZ, TERMSTART, TERMENDE, VORMENGE)
                           values (SEQ_SAP_ZPCP12.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(0), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(1), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(2)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(3)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(4)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(5)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(6)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(7)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(8), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Row(9), "dd.MM.yyyy", Nothing)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Row(10)
```